# What is the proper way to weight a response variable for a decision tree?

Tags: cart

I want to develop a decision tree regression model that predicts the cost of an insurance policy (known as pure premium) and use the exposures as a weight.

What is the correct way to do a weighted decision tree regression model?  Do I just divide the response variable by the exposure (weight)?